# error occured during Autocomplete usage in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete

I had tried to do autosuggest in dropdown in React, but I get some errors.

> react-dom.development.js?61bb:16543 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'indexOf' of undefined

Here is my code:

```js
let filteredOptions = patientsMasterData.ReferredBy && 
  patientsMasterData.ReferredBy.filter(referredObj => {
    return { options: referredObj.RefName.indexOf(this.state.value) } !== -1;
  });

return (
  <ReactAutocomplete
    name="ReferredBy"
    items={[
      filteredOptions.map(referredObj => ({
        options: referredObj.RefName,
        values: referredObj.RefID
      }))
    ]}
    shouldItemRender={(item, value) => item.options.indexOf(value) > -1}
    getItemValue={item => item.options}
    renderItem={(item, highlighted) => (
      <div
        key={item.values}
        style={{ backgroundColor: highlighted ? "#eee" : "transparent" }}
      >
        {item.options}
      </div>
    )}
    value={this.state.value}
    onChange={e => this.setState({ value: onGetTimelyFiling(e.target.value) })}
    onSelect={value => this.setState({ value })}
  />
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure all objects in the `ReferredBy` array has a `RefName` property? It looks like some of them don't.

Comment: ya.. I swear...